# How can i enable dynamic scripting in AWS ES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, groovy

I am using aws elastic service and indexed 650 000 data. 
I need to add two new fields to the already indexed documents. 
When I tried to call the updateByQuery function got the error, 'scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled'. 
I have fixed it by adding
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on on elasticsearch.yml and it works perfectly on local . 
How can I add this configuration on aws es ? 
I am getting the same error when I am updating documents in aws elastic service.

Here is my code. I want to update all records ( where "device"= deviceVal) by adding new  fields Site and Time.

```
var site = 'some value';
var deviceVal = '123'; 

var theScript = {
    "inline": "ctx._source.Site = '"+ site + "';ctx._source.Time = '"+ new Date().getTime() + "'"
}   
var match = {
    "match": { "device": deviceVal }
}

client.updateByQuery({
    index: 'my_index',
    type:'txt',

    "body": {
        "query": match, 
        "script":theScript
    }

}, function (error, response) {
    // console.log("success")
    console.log('error--',error)
    console.log('response--',response)
});
```

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987919/not-allowed-to-reindex-elasticsearch/38987991#38987991 (hint: the `_update_by_query` endpoint [is not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987919/not-allowed-to-reindex-elasticsearch/38987991#38987991) by the AWS ES Service). You're better off reindexing your data into a new index.

Comment: @Val , How can I add new fields with  dynamic value  while reindexing with logstash ? . I need to add a new  field 'Site' to the document and The value of  'Site' depends on the 'device' field which is already in document.

Comment: @Val , How can I add new fields with  dynamic value  while reindexing with logstash ? . I need to add two new  fields 'Site' & 'Location' to the document.  The values of  'Site' & 'Location' depends on the 'device' field which is already in document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987919/not-allowed-to-reindex-elasticsearch/38987991#38987991) where we use logstash to reindex into an AWS ES cluster, you simply need to add one more transformation where `# add other transformations here` is mentioned.

In your case the input part needs to contain a query for the device:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["my-elasticsearch-domain.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:80"]
   index => "my_index"
   query => '{"query": {"match":{"device": "123"}}}'
   docinfo => true
  }
}
```

And the filter part would boil down to this, i.e. we rename the `@timestamp` field and add the `Site` field:

```
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version" ]
  rename => { "@timestamp" => "Time" }
  add_field => { "Site" => "some value" }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I have multiple values for device like 123, 456,789 etc then can I reindex  all documents in single step ? The value of Site changed with device. Or do I need to execute the logstash script multiple times for each device value ?

Comment: If you only have a dozen or so devices to update, I'd suggest running this manually a couple times. If we're talking a few dozens, hundreds or more, then the above solution can be automatized, the simplest being with a shell script that generates the logstash config and runs logstash for every configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much Val. I think shell script is a nice idea.

Comment: How can I set environment variables in logstash? I have tried with shell script. 
Set the value as follows.
export site="Hotel California"
And in my .conf file 
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version"]
  add_field => { 
    "Site" => "${site}"
  }
 }
}
But the field site is not updated from the environent variable. Its value saved as "${site}".